# How to convert flash circle object coordinates for canvas/raphael.js?

Tags: html, flash, canvas, geometry, raphael

I have some simple flash animations that I am converting into HTML5 image maps, that trigger some drawing upon `<area>` rollovers.

Problem being is that all the circles (representing roll-over points) are given to me as flash circle object coordinates. The points in question are formed at the joining of imaginary lines that go from the circle’s topmost and leftmost points (marked by the dashed red lines in the image below).

[image: flash circle coords]

But to draw my circles in HTML5 (using raphael.js currently), I have to to give a center coordinate: `var c = paper.circle(x, y, radius)`.

So, for example, if I have flash circle object (532.20,30.35) with a height and width of 19.80 (again from the point where the imaginary lines intersect) how can I calculate the values I need for drawing a circle at its center point in the canvas?

Comment: you mean `newx = 532.20 + 19.80 / 2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just subtract the radius from the x and y:

```
x = x - radius;
y = y - radius;
```

In your case:

```
radius = 19.8 * 0.5
x = 532.2 - radius;
y = 30.35 - radius;
```

This will draw the circle *center* at the original x and y (it moves the circle left and  up).

If you want the circle in the effectively same position as the original but have to move the coordinate system then you add radius instead.